# Why is flexslider not loading "off-page" images?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm working on this website:
http://www.lakeofthewoodsadventures.com/local/index.html

I got the homepage image slider working, but it won't render the last two pages of the slider, no matter which files they are.

My question is: why is it doing that? Is it because it considers what is "off-page" not needed? The images are the same size, 1280x480 (scaled to 340 height).

Here are my settings:

Script in Head:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="flexslider.css" type="text/css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.flexslider.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
      $(window).load(function() {
        $('.flexslider').flexslider({
            animation: "slide",
            controlNav: false,
            animationLoop: true,  
            slideshow: true, 
            useCSS: true,
            itemWidth: 900,
        });
      });
</script>
```

Markup:

```
        <div class="slide-container row">
        <div class="flexslider slideEdit">
            <ul class="slides">
                <li>
                  <img src="images/slide6.JPG" alt="Slide 6">
                </li>
                <li>
                  <img src="images/slide7.JPG" alt="Slide 7">
                </li>
                <li>
                  <img src="images/slide8.JPG" alt="Slide 8">
                </li>
                <li>
                  <img src="images/slide9.jpg" alt="Slide 9">
                </li>
                <li>
                  <img src="images/slide10.jpg" alt="Slide 10">
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is because those images do not exist (404 File Not Found): 
http://www.lakeofthewoodsadventures.com/local/images/slide9.jpg
http://www.lakeofthewoodsadventures.com/local/images/slide10.jpg

Looks like it is a capitalization issue:
http://www.lakeofthewoodsadventures.com/local/images/slide9.JPG
http://www.lakeofthewoodsadventures.com/local/images/slide10.JPG

Comment: Thank you. I could've sworn I checked that. Perhaps when I was testing, I didn't refresh the cache properly.

Comment: Easy mistake. I would recommend always having your files all lowercase so that there is no confusion.

Comment: Yeah. It's been a long day. Thanks again. Now I just need to figure out why the slider-container isn't scaling responsively...